# How to calculate interim and long-run multipliers in ARDL models with >1 lag?

Tags: time-series, stata, ardl

I have calculated an ARDL(24,36) model with 1 independent variable. The data is monthly, hence the inclusion of so many lags.

I am trying to calculate the interim multiplier (the cumulative effect at a given point in time) and the total long-run multiplier.

I have seen the latter formula given as (B0+B1)/(1-A1)

Where B0 is the coefficient on the independent variable at time t, B1 is the coefficient on the independent variable at t-1 and A1 is the coefficient on the dependent variable at t-1. However, this formula seems to be limited to ARDL(1,1) models.

In models with more than 1 lag, what is the interim multiplier at lag k and what is the total long-run multiplier?

Answer (score 2):

For an ARDL(n,m) model using your notation the multiplier is given by:

$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^mb_i}{1-\sum_{j=1}^na_j}$

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks a lot. Does this hold if there is more than 1 independent variable as well?

Comment: Yes, as long as two things hold. 1, You analyze each variable separately, i.e. the b coefficients are on lags of the same variable. And 2, there are no interaction terms.

Comment: Hi, any idea how to do the above long-run multiplier calculation (with also the standard error obtained) in Stata?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do what you are asking in STATA. It has been over 5 years since I worked with STATA daily though. My suggestion for an unknown way to calculate the standard error for that unknown value would be to just bootstrap the standard error by sampling randomly from your data with replacement, run the regression on the sampled data, doing the calculation that I describe on using the method I describe above, record the outcome, and then rinse and repeat like 1000X. Take the 97.5% percentile and the 2.5% percentile of the results to get your confidence interval.

Comment: Or take the standard deviation of your results and claim that as your bootstrapped standard error.

Comment: It is an ugly way to go about it, but the theory supports bootstrapping. So as long as you have the compute to do the heavy lifting, it is a great way to go about it. If you are really clever, you can parallelize the process to make it go faster, but that's probably more effort than is worth it for a fairly simple regression.